# Visual studio 2008 debugging issues

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008

Every time I try to debug my code I get the error message

The program '[2840] link.exe: Native' has exited with code 1171 (0x493).

The code has an error in it, but I can't fix it without a functioning debugger. How do I fix it?

Comment: a quick search on google returned [this](http://www.pc-library.com/errors/error-code/1171-0x493/). Does it help?

Comment: No. That is some mouse related issue and we're not working with that at all.

Comment: The issue is with my link.exe file not loading a file properly. This has something to do with the crappy environmental settings of the virtual machine that I am using.

Comment: Right, LNK1171 points at an install problem.  You'll have to make it uncrappy, we can't help you with that.

Comment: Alright thanks. Workin on it.